# multiple emails attachment are not working

Tags: php

i am trying to send multiple email same time. it works sometime it not.

Help me ....

```
# DYNAMICALLY GET ALL ATTACHMENTS   
    for($i=1;$i<count($_FILES)+1; $i++){
        if(!empty($_FILES['atachment'.$i]['tmp_name'])){
            $file_name = $_FILES['atachment'.$i]['name'];
            $temp_name = $_FILES['atachment'.$i]['tmp_name'];
            $file_location = $_FILES['atachment'.$i]['tmp_name'];
            $filetype = $_FILES['atachment'.$i]['type'];
            move_uploaded_file($temp_name,'temp_upload/'.$file_name);   
            $files[] = 'temp_upload/'.$file_name;
        }
    }

    # EMAIL SETTING
    $headers = "From:$from";

    $semi_rand = md5(time());
    $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";

    // headers for attachment
    $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

    // multipart boundary
    $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . "–{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $message . "\n\n"; 

    # PREPARE ATTACMENTS
    for($x=0;$x<count($files);$x++){
        $file = fopen($files[$x],"rb");
        $data = fread($file,filesize($files[$x]));
        fclose($file);
        $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
        $message .= "Content-Type: {\"application/octet-stream\"};\n" . " name=\"$files[$x]\"\n" .
        "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"$files[$x]\"\n" .
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";
        $message .= "–{$mime_boundary}–\n";
    }

    # CHECK IF SEND FUNCTION
    $ok = @mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); 
    if ($ok) { 
        echo "<p>mail sent to $to!</p>"; 
    } else { 
        echo "<p>mail could not be sent!</p>"; 
    } enter code here
```

Comment: Not exactly an answer to your question, but i thought u might wanna do stuff like this with http://swiftmailer.org/

Comment: Why is `mail()` function used with `@`? Remove it to see warnings/errors, occurred while sending - this should help you to understand the reason of a problem.

Comment: mail() is under powered and not recommend for this. something that makes its own socket connection to the mail server like phpmailer is a much better idea.

Answer (score 0):

doing wrong thing here:

```
// multipart boundary
$message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . "–{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $message . "\n\n";
```

must be used as:

```
// multipart boundary
$message = "–{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . "Content- Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
```

If you want to know exact working then kindly read the MIME Specification for sending email [here](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3851.txt) and [here](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1521.html)

Answer (score -2):

I don't know PHP but it looks like you are trying to attach multiple files at once. In Visual Basic you are required to attach files one at a time. Try using a loop to attach one file at a time until all files are attached. Again, i don't know PHP though so this is pure speculation from what i know in Visual Basic

Comment: Uhm, looks like he *is* using a loop to attach one file at a time...?!

Comment: Again, i don't know PHP but to me it looks like he is using that For to build multiple emails. There is one loop in his code and it seems like its doing MUCH more than just adding an attachment. But alas, i do not know PHP.